# Alternating colors for consecutive groups of events in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table that looks sort of like this:

[image: Example data]

I need a way to automatically alternate the row colors. As it stands right now, I have a large list of data that looks like that, but with no grouping.

What I would like is for excel to check the color of the row below a given row, and if that row contains "End of Product", change the color accordingly, in order to demarcate different groups of events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conditional formatting use a formula as the rule.

Use this formula:

```
=ISODD(COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,"End of Product"))
```

Pay attention to what is and what is not absolute.

Then apply it to your data range:

[image]